# want to insert a row in a table after clicking a link in my rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a rails application from the that have a list of members,
so what i want is that when ever i open a member i want to have a link so that when they click on it ,it will save the current date and time with the membership number.

Comment: wow!!! thnx for tellin me cuz i didnt know b4...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to modifying the `updated_at` field for that record in the DB. I assume you followed proper practices here and you do have an `updated_at` column.

You can use the `button_to` helper to call you `update` action in the `users_controller`. In the controller you have, do the following:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.touch

  # render/redirect as you wish
end
```

Touch will set the `updated_at` time to the current time, alternatively you can also use `model.touch(:column_name)` if you have a timestamp column with a different name then updated at.

Comment: thnx @brupm ,well yea you rite i followed the proper practice and now i have another table called clocks and from the list of members all of them have a link called "clock" so that anytime i click clock it will insert in the clocks database..e.g membership number,date and time

Comment: what i want is to insert into another table not to update the "updated_at" column

Comment: I'd recommend you read Agile Web Development with Rails: http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails